# How to create a custom log filter in enterprise library 4.0?

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library 4.0 and I can't find any documentation on creating a custom logging filter.  Has anyone done this or seen any good online documentation on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using Custom Filters in the Enterprise Library Logging Block](https://web.archive.org/web/20160512123637/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/.NETonMyMind/archive/2006/05/15/78201.aspx)

Great Article.

Answer (score 1):

Perusing through EntLib's source code would probably help you if the documentation is scant; it's well-written and well-commented.